# Facebook dev - loading fbml & html code into a div in an iFrame via Ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook, fbml, xfbml

I've got an iframe application that's working fine and rendering fbml in facebook. But the whole app is built using ajax calls to load large chunks of pages. Several of these have < fb: tags that aren't being rendered when they load. I tried the code below, which is then loaded into a div in my index page, but it doesn't show anything at all, no html, no fb rendering, nothing. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?? Thanks so much!!

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 600px;">
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml>

<!-- all of my html and my php and my fb tags go in here, for example: -->
<fb:name uid="my_real_user_id" useyou=\"false\"></fb:name>

</fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

I hope my question was clear. If not, just let me know I'll explain in more detail! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have look at this question

[Loading Facebook fb:profile-pic via AJAX in Facebook Connect site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462584/loading-facebook-fbprofile-pic-via-ajax-in-facebook-connect-site)