# Using Jquery to load Facebook fb:profile-pic - not working in IE

Tags: jquery, facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

I followed the tips given on

[Loading Facebook fb:profile via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462584/loading-facebook-fbprofile-pic-via-ajax-in-facebook-connect-site)

In my app, I am basically loading more comments posted by the user via Jquery and along with each comment showing the user's picture using the fb:profile-pic tag

This is a sample of how I'm building the string via Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(".more_comments").live('click',function() 
  {
    $.getJSON("/store/more-swipes",function(data) 
    {
      newcomment += "<fb:profile-pic uid='"+data.fb_userid+"'/>";
      newcomment += ""+data.user_name+": ";
      newcomment += ""+data.user_comment+": ";
     $("#morecomments").append(newcomment);
    });
return false;
  });
});
```

So the profile-pic was not being displayed - After reading the above link, I added

```
if ( FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree )
  setTimeout( FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree, 0 );
```

The weird thing now is - its working in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE
Cant figure out why.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the reason why - but making this change - the code started working in IE

From

```
newcomment += "<fb:profile-pic uid='12345'/>";
```

To

```
newcomment += "<fb:profile-pic uid='12345'></fb:profile-pic";
```

Hope it helps someone else - I wasted a lot of time debugging this one.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in the `load` event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code here...
});
```

Comment: sarfraz thhanks for your post - my code is part of the $(".more_comments").live('click',function() { method which is called when the user clicks on the "more comments" link - I will edit the question to reflect that - So how would I add the code to the $(window).load function and why is that necessary

Comment: @Gublooo: The `load` event fires when all page DOM tree has been parsed and all external resources have loaded into the page. You should place your code inside that replacing my comment and then see if it works.

Comment: thanks - right now all my code is placed in $(document).ready(function() { - should i replace this method with the window.load method

Comment: I tried replacing the $(document).ready(function() with $(window).load(function(){ - it still doesn't work in IE - it works fine in other browsers - Thanks